# How to decrease routing rate (TCP/UDP) when CPU idle is very low

Tags: linux, networking, embedded-linux, tcp, openwrt

I am developing a router, and I am trying to make it more robust.
I am using Iperf to create TCP data streams between 2 PCs that are connected to the router, but when I am getting to high data rate my sirq are getting to about 90-90%.
Is there a way in Linux (I am using Openwrt) to decrease the routing rate or to drop TCP/UDP packets, when the CPU idle is very low ?
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I have a solution, I will monitor the idle by calling TOP, if the idle is low, I will use iptables cli to drop packets, for a period of time.